# PDFJs print directly witouth showing the PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I've to print from Silverlight a PDF avoiding to pass via Silverlight printing queue (it generate mega-fat print queue), so I've tought of using PDF.JS to show/print the pdf directly

I've managed to show a PDF correctly with the toolbar and the print button,
when I click it I perform the

```
PDFJS.getDocument(THEFILEPATH).then(function (pdf) {
    window.print();
})
```

and this opens the printdialog correctly, but it calls the browser's print so if I don't specify the content it doesn't print

Can I pass the PDF content to window print somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the default viewer that pdf.js provides or did you build your own? I'm trying to do basically the same thing as you right now, I put together this jsbin based off answers from the pdf.js IRC. Have not yet been able to get it to work though, this is the process they recommended. http://jsbin.com/soveseloxa/1/edit

Comment: I ve. tried with default viewer...by the way it prints a browser page not the pdf itself... am Tring another solution but at payment... give you the name tomorrow (I'm not at office now)

Comment: Sounds good, I'm chatting with a dev on the pdf.js team right now. I'll let you know if I make any headway with it after speaking with them.

Comment: Hello, here I'm the product I'm testing is this one http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc/ but I've to test if I can use it as I need (with Silverlight) ... do you had any news @Stavros_S after having talked with the devs?